# When I add tableview to the ViewController,tableview is not added correctly

Tags: swift, uitableview, interface-builder

[image: this is the storyboard when I added a tableview]

The output of this tableview not appearing correctly.what is the reason to come like that

Comment: That's not how it looks when you run it.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. How are you referencing the table in the ViewController class, how are the tableVIew delegate functions defined. What are the constraints you've set up in the layout...

Comment: @Sasang  I just embedded with navigationcontroller,and then I drag tableview into vc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the tableView that you just drag into a view will have default properties associated with it. When you run it on a phone/sim it doesn't actually have the 'Table View' heading (that's just there to make it easier to design the storyboard), it'll have a white background with no rows and will look like there's nothing on the screen. Furthermore it may not even be at the location you placed it at depending on how the constraints default when rendering the scene.

It seems like you have a little to learn about how this works. When creating a new storyboard, generally speaking you associate a ViewController class to it. Assuming you have dynamic data to display on the table, you connect references to the tableView to the class, then you need to assign a delegate to the table and then implement the protocols. Then if you have custom cells, it adds a little more to do. Theres several great tutorials from Apple itself on how to do all this in swift.

If you just want to see how the table would look; in the storyboard itself you can create prototype cells in the table and design it out that way.

Either way, make sure you read about constraints and how to make it look right when rendering on a phone. Just dragging things onto the story board does not mean that when you finally run it, it will look exactly as you designed it. You need to specify how components align relative to each other, which is essentially what constraints do.